# SQL 5 most borrowed books

Tags: sql, oracle

I use Oracle

```
    Socio(codigo,apellido_nombre,direccion,telefono,fecha_alt)
    Libro(codigo,titulo_libro,tema)
    Prestamos(codigoSocio,codigoLibro)

**********
Member(code,last_name,first_name,address,telephone,date_alt)
Book(code,title_book,subject)
Loans(codeMember,codeBook)
```

With these 3 tables, how can I get the most borrowed books? (1+book)

and the most borrowed book  (1book)

```
" Select codebook from  Loans
group by codebook 
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What SQL engine?  show some effort we'll help you when you have trouble.  Sample Data & Expected results also help.

Comment: Member(code,last_name,first_name,address,telephone,date_alt)
Book(code,title_book,subject)
Loans(codeMember,codeBook)

Comment: we could order by count(Loans) DESC and limit to top 5, we could we could group by the book name.  order by group by and limit or top depending on the SQL engine...

Comment: i use oracle 8i

Comment: Step 1: Write a query that returns all books and their loan counts. Step 2: Pick 5 most loaned.

Comment: this is good? Select codebook from  Loans
group by codebook 
order by count(*) desc

Comment: It's a start.  We still need to *limit* the *rownum* to the *top* 5.  Maybe `where rownum <=5`?  But that wouldn't handle ties well.

Comment: This query then shows you downwardly for more borrowed books? if so, you could do a procedure to create a cursor and make 5 fetch

Comment: but how do I show 5 more borrowed books and the 5 partners who have taken it?

Comment: And that would be why I asked for sample data/expected results.  Now you want to see the Member too?  I thought it was just the 5 most borrowed books.  Do you expect each member on their own row, together on same row?  By working though and showing the expected results you help us help you.

Comment: The problem is I don't have the database, I should do it on paper.

Comment: @wallcroft - Here's database for you and everyone: https://livesql.oracle.com/ 
You need to create data with your example.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I presume you want the name of the book with most rows in the LOANS table. The below query will return that book.

`SELECT title_book
FROM book
WHERE code = (SELECT MAX(CODEBOOK)
FROM LOANS)`